# Bash export command

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am encountering a strange problem with my 64-bit Ubuntu - on the *export* command.

Basically, I have got a VM installation on Ubuntu on my Windows 7 system, and I am trying to pass commands from my Windows system to my VM installation using a custom (given by client) software.

So, on my VM, when I do:

```
export foo=bar
echo $foo
```

everything works as expected.

However, when I do the same through the custom software (which basically passes the Linux command as a string to the bash shell), I get:

```
export: command not found
```

I tried looking at the shell (using the custom software), using:

```
echo $SHELL > shell.txt
```

And I get */bin/bash* which is expected and I still get the *"export: command not found error"*.

How can I fix this?

Comment: export isn't a real command (i.e. not in /bin, /usr/bin etc.) it's handled by bash internally. You could do bash -c "export foo=bar;echo \$foo" if you wanted to...

Comment: What is this custom software you speak of?

Comment: What Adam says might be the key to your problem. `export` is a bash builtin. `echo` is a binary that resides in your `$PATH`

Comment: What is the 'custom (given by client)' software?

Comment: Thanks you guys for your response. The "custom software" is a bunch of java code my client has written, and it contains a feature to run linux commands (basically passes the commands as a string to shell). I will try the bash -c option and update you guys with the result.

Comment: Adam, amazing! bash -c does the trick. I am not entirely sure what bash -c does (I am on my way to google this), but any insight from you would help too! Could you please answer it as an "answer" and I will accept this?

Comment: Adam, on the same note, once I set the env variable using bash -c "export foo=bar", can I do something like: bash -c "cp im.log bm.log image1.png \$foo"? When I try doing this, I get a foo: undefined variable error :(

Comment: You should do it the way Adam mentions. `bash -c "export foo=bar; cp im.log bm.log image1.png \$foo"`. i.e. Chain the commands separated by `;`. Each invocation of `bash -c` starts with a fresh environment. Obviously, the variable is reported as undefined.

Comment: Arjun, thanks for that. If you could write it as an answer Id be glad to accept it.

Comment: @JohnJ - Done. Feel free to answer your own question as well! It is good to have questions 'answered' irrespective of who does it.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`export` is a Bash builtin, `echo` is an executable in your `$PATH`. So `export` is interpreted by Bash as is, without spawning a new process.

You need to get Bash to interpret your command, which you can pass as a string with the `-c` option:

```
bash -c "export foo=bar; echo \$foo"
```

ALSO:

Each invocation of `bash -c` starts with a fresh environment. So something like:

```
bash -c "export foo=bar"
bash -c "echo \$foo"
```

will not work. The second invocation does not remember `foo`.

Instead, you need to chain commands separated by `;` in a single invocation of `bash -c`:

```
bash -c "export foo=bar; echo \$foo"
```

Comment: The "ALSO" paragraph helped me solve my problem. Thanks

Comment: I executed `$ bash -c "export foo=bar"`, but it says `$ bash -c "echo \$foo"
foo: Undefined variable.`

Comment: This does not overwrite the value on my centos 5.11, the echo in this line still prints the old value

Comment: @DavidDunham there are two snippets in the answer: The first one calls export and echo in *one* bash invocation and the other in two separate ones. Accordingly, the first one should "overwrite" the variable (although only temporarily, and then print the new value) and the second should not. What did you observe?

Answer (score 6):

If you can’t use the "export" command then *just* use:

```
setenv path /dir
```

Like this

```
setenv ORACLE_HOME /data/u01/apps/oracle/11.2.0.3.0
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are using [C shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_shell) -

```
setenv PATH $PATH":/home/tmp"
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably because it's trying to execute "export" as an external command, and it's a shell internal.

Answer (score 1):

Changing from Bash to *sh* scripting made my script work:

```
!/bin/sh
```

Comment: actually you were right as well. sometimes the default shell is not either bash or sh, using this command fixes the issue

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain that the software (and not yourself, since your test actually only shows the shell used as default for your user) uses */bin/bash*?

Answer (score 0):

`SHELL` is an environment variable, and so it's not the most reliable for what you're trying to figure out. If your tool is using a shell which doesn't set it, it will retain its old value.

Use `ps` to figure out what's really going on.

Answer (score -3):

Follow *these* steps to *remove* "bash export command not found." Terminal open error fix>>>>>>

Open a terminal and type:

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

After loading nano:

Remove the all 'export PATH = ...' lines and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> to save file and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> to exit.

Now the terminal opening error will be fixed...

Comment: 'export PATH Files in the borrom of the file