# Cloudera - JAVA_HOME not set

Tags: java, cloudera

I am pretty novice when it comes to Ubuntu but I am trying to follow along with the install instructions for Cloudera located [here](https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/CDH4DOC/Installing+CDH4+on+a+Single+Linux+Node+in+Pseudo-distributed+Mode).

At step 1, I am getting to following error:

```
brock@brock-hpserver:~$ sudo -u hdfs hdfs namenode -format
Error: JAVA_HOME is not set and could not be found.
```

However, although I could be wrong, I believe I have everything set up properly:

```
brock@brock-hpserver:~$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64
brock@brock-hpserver:~$ echo $PATH
/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:JAVA_HOME/bin
```

And finally my java version:

```
brock@brock-hpserver:~$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_24"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11.5) (6b24-1.11.5-0ubuntu1~12.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.  I simply just want to poke around and learn Hadoop on a spare machine at home.

Answer (score 3):

I met the same problem, just add `JAVA_HOME="directory_to_JDK"` setting into the `/etc/environment`, and it works.

Answer (score 2):

The JAVA_HOME is defined for your process, but not for the process in which the `sudo` is running.  `export` the JAVA_HOME definition.  I don't recall the syntax, but I believe it's similar to `export JAVA_HOME=/drive/dir1/dir2/java`

If that does not work, JAVA_HOME can be defined at the system level, for all processes.  It's been a long time, I don't recall how.  But hopefully there's enough here to allow you to Google.

[Here's a SO link about export.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10108950/bash-export-command)