# Error: JAVA_HOME is not set and could not be found. How to set JAVA_HOME permanently in Hadoop?

Tags: java, linux, hadoop, installation

I installed [CDH in Pseudo distributed mode](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH4/latest/CDH4-Quick-Start/cdh4qs_topic_3.html) on Ubuntu 12.04.

Prior to it, I installed Java and exported my `JAVA_HOME` variables to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle` and exported `JAVA_HOME` to `path` as well, for both root as well as other users (self, hdfs). and it was `echo`ed correctly as well as showed up in `env` results.

Still my CDH installation complained of `JAVA_HOME` not found/set so I added `JAVA_HOME` to `/etc/environment` as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14173024/cloudera-java-home-not-set) and the entry `Defaults env_keep+=JAVA_HOME` in `/etc/sudoers`

All works fine, I can check services are running via `Jps`, **but when I  try to stop them** as root it says,

```
service hadoop-hdfs-datanode stop
 * Stopping Hadoop datanode: 
Error: JAVA_HOME is not set and could not be found.
```

same goes for all other services.

I don't have `hadoop-env.sh` in my installation, the only one present is at `/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/example-confs/conf.secure/hadoop-env.sh` which is an example I believe

Comment: Did you try putting `JAVA_HOME` explicitly in the above path `hadoop-env.sh` (search for JAVA_HOME in that)?

Answer (score 3):

Cloudera uses [BIGTOP](http://bigdata4me.wordpress.com/2012/11/01/hadoop-script-tips-using-apache-bigtop-utility-to-detect-java_home/) to try and detect JAVA_HOME for you. The practice is questionable at best, if you ask me.

You can make this behave correctly by editing a bigtop configuration file. On Debian/Ubuntu, add this to `/etc/default/bigtop-utils`:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/correct/path/to/java-home
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting the JAVA_HOME in /etc/profile too. Can you please check this link too [Hadoop: «ERROR : JAVA_HOME is not set»](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8827102/hadoop-error-java-home-is-not-set)

Answer (score 0):

You should edit **`etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh`** and add   `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/latest` This way your `JAVA_HOME` will be set permanently

[From hadoop documentation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html)

Unpack the downloaded Hadoop distribution. In the distribution, edit the file `etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh` to define some parameters as follows:

```
set to the root of your Java installation
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/latest
```